# What are differences between cluster MKL statically and dynamically?

Tags: intel-mkl

I wonder about the differences between cluster MKL statically and dynamically. Can anyone give me an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static and dynamic linking is used to include libraries in executable and to use libraries separately from executable respectively.

Linking statically can be problematic sometimes because the more complex your operating environment or application, the more likely redundant copies of the library are included. This may result in performance issues (oversubscription of threads) and even incorrect results. To link dynamically, be sure the PATH environment variable is defined correctly. You can also use the Intel Link Line advisor tool to see which libraries are recommended for a particular use case.

Link:https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl/link-line-advisor.html